# ngModle value is not getting reflected in UI for 'ng-pick-datetime' date picker control

Tags: datepicker, angular7

I am trying to transform ngModel value depends upon current time zone value and binding back to date picker control in Angular UI. (Angular 7)

html:

```
<input placeholder="Date Time:"[(ngModel)]="dateTime"
              (ngModleChange)="updateDate(dateTime)"
               [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt">
        <owl-date-time #dt></owl-date-time>
```

component:

```
 this.datetime= "5/23/2019 8.52 AM EST"
```

Since `<owl-date-time>` uses `moment.js` internally and the date value is selected and bind to input control is type date hence its not accepting string format and not binding back with actual string format:`5/23/2019 8.52 AM EST`

`5/23/2019 8.52 AM EST` value hast to be displayed in date picker control.

Comment: Is the updateDate() method running? When you initialize the dateTime property is the initial date correct? Show your component code as well.

Comment: Yes and even i can see  formatted  date string  with ng-model-reflect value  when i inspect html too.

Comment: Can you share the updateDate() method as well.

Comment: public updateDate(selDate) {

    return moment.utc(selDate).tz('Europe/London').format('GMT');  // Expected output string : MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM (GMT)
     // return moment.utc(selDate).tz('America/New_York').format('EST'); //MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM (EST)
   
  }

Comment: You are going to either return GMT or EST, which one? Or do you have multiple inputs with updateDate() method that will either return GMT or EST?

Comment: yest multiple use cases. based on time zone drop down value in UI. so it would be GMT and EST..